# boxbuffergeometry is not part of the three namespace!React problem

Tags: reactjs, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

boxbuffergeometry is not part of the three namespace! Please help!
Even if the package is installed and tried a lot of possibilities the problem persisted.

1. installed the package required.
2. updated the package required.
3. checked on internet.
4. cleared cache no change.
5. restarted the application still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`<primitive object={new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)} />`

In the context of react-three-fiber (R3F), a primitive tag is a lower-level component that allows you to inject any three.js object directly into the scene graph.

[Check this link from pmndrs docs it has the same usage](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/how-it-works)

Comment: Any reference or docu for  this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found this when searching the same issues -

it's poorly documented change, but essentially I believe BoxGeometry just IS BoxBufferGeometry now, and so the reason fro BoxBufferGeometry is gone, as is the namespace.

If you see here in the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry

At the top of page you see BufferGeometry follow by an arrow, that is their notation that BoxGeometry inherits from BufferGeometry.

I read some other forum posts etc which were sort of obscure but I'm pretty confident in just calling BoxGeometry and getting the BufferGeometry efficiency out of the gate